# Where can I save my clients’ choices on my e-commerce shop so I can see what the bought

Tags: php, e-commerce

I created a html website with e-commerce shop. I created a shopping cart with javascript ofc, but now I want to create a checkout form on a subpage after cart. But I can’t do it without saving clients’ choices so I know what to send them. How can I save products chosen by them by clicking the button „checkout” And where do it do it? I think i should do it in php but im not sure...
my cart.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Caroline | Homemade Candles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    

    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="darmowadostawa">
    <p>100% DOMOWYCH ŚWIECZEK | Gwarancja komfortu</p>
</div>
<div class="emailugory">
    <a href="mailto:#">E-mail:xxx</a>
    <a href="tel:#">Numer telefonu:xxx-xxx-xxx</a>
</div>
        
        
        </div>
        
        <nav class="yolo">

            
            <ul id="MenuItems">
<li class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="logooficjalne.png" class="carolinepng"></a></li>
        <li><a href="onas.html">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="swieceswiateczne.html">Świece świąteczne</a></li>
                <li><a href="naturalneswiecezpachowe.html">Naturalne świece zapachowe</a></li>      
                <li><a href="szklo.html">Świece zapachowe w szkle</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#.html">Zapachy</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="owocowe.html">Owocowe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="słodkie.html">Słodkie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="eleganckie.html">Eleganckie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kwiatowe.html">Kwiatowe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="świąteczne.html">Świąteczne</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>



 <li class="cart"> <a href="cart.html"> <i class="fab fa-opencart"><img src="cart.png" width="20px" margin-top="0px;"></i><span class="cart-span">0</span> </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()">"
    </div>
</div>
<div class="products-container">
    <div class="product-header">
        <h5 class="product-title">Produkt</h5>
        <h5 class="price">Cena</h5>
        <h5 class="quantity">Ilość</h5>
        <h5 class="total">Razem</h5>

    </div>
    <div class="products">
    </div>
</div>

<h1 class="metodadostawy">Metoda dostawy</h1>




 <!----- footer ----->
 
        <footer>
            <div class="column">
            <ul class="footer-links-main">
                <li><a href="onas.html">O nas</a></li>
                <li><a href="produkty.html">Produkty</a></li>
                <li><a href="polityka.html">Regulamin</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="footer-sm"> 
                <div class="column2">
                <h3 class="kontakth3">Kontakt</h3>
                <p class="kontaktp">Adres e-mail:xxx</p>
                <p class="kontaktp">Numer telefonu:xxx</p>
                        </div>
        </div>
        </footer>
    <!---- js for toggle menu--->
    <script>
        var MenuItems = document.getElementById("MenuItems");

        MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";

        function menutoggle(){
            if (MenuItems.style.maxHeight == "0px")
            {
                MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px";
            }
            else
            {
                MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.2.3/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

my js for cart (local storage)

```
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

let products = [
{
    name: "Świeczka o zapachu truskawki",
    tag: "truskawka",
    price: 20,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: "Świeczka o zapachu wanilii",
    tag: "wanilia",
    price: 20,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: "Świeczka o zapachu kawy",
    tag: 'kawa',
    price: 20,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
name: "Świeczka o zapachu kupy",
tag: 'kupa',
price:20,
inCart: 0.
},
{
    name: "Świeczka o zapachu borówki",
    tag: "borówka",
    price: 20,
    inCart: 0,
},
{
    name: "Świeczka o zapachu borówki",
    tag: "borówka",
    price: 20,
    inCart: 0,
}
]; 

for(let i=0; i< carts.length; i++) {
    carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartNumbers(products[i]);
        totalCost(products[i]);
    });
}

function onLoadCartNumbers() {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    if( productNumbers ) {
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers;
    }
}

function cartNumbers(product, action) {
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

   
    if( action ) {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers - 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers - 1;
        console.log("action running");
    } else if( productNumbers ) {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers + 1;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", 1);
        document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = 1;
    }
    setItems(product);
}

function setItems(product) {
    // let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    // productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    if(cartItems != null) {
        let currentProduct = product.tag;
    
        if( cartItems[currentProduct] == undefined ) {
            cartItems = {
                ...cartItems,
                [currentProduct]: product
            }
        } 
        cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;

    } else {
        product.inCart = 1;
        cartItems = { 
            [product.tag]: product
        };
    }

    localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

function totalCost( product, action ) {
    let cart = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");

    if( action) {
        cart = parseInt(cart);

        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cart - product.price);
    } else if(cart != null) {
        
        cart = parseInt(cart);
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cart + product.price);
    
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
    }
}

function displayCart() {
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    let cart = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
    cart = parseInt(cart);

    let productContainer = document.querySelector('.products');
    
    if( cartItems && productContainer ) {
        productContainer.innerHTML = '';
        Object.values(cartItems).map( (item, index) => {
            productContainer.innerHTML += 
            `<div class="product"><ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon><img src="${item.tag}.png" />
                <span class="sm-hide">${item.name}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price sm-hide">${item.price},00zł</div>
            <div class="quantity">
<ion-icon class="decrease" name="arrow-back-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                    <span>${item.inCart}</span>
              
                <ion-icon class="increase" name="arrow-forward-circle-outline"></ion-icon>  
            </div>
            <div class="total">${item.inCart * item.price},00zł</div>`;
        });

        productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="basketTotalContainer">
                <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">Razem w koszu</h4>
                <h4 class="basketTotal">${cart},00zł</h4>
            </div>`

   deleteButtons();
        manageQuantity();
    }
}

function manageQuantity() {
    let decreaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.decrease');
    let increaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.increase');
    let currentQuantity = 0;
    let currentProduct = '';
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

    for(let i=0; i < increaseButtons.length; i++) {
        decreaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(cartItems);
            currentQuantity = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);
            currentProduct = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').trim();
            console.log(currentProduct);

            if( cartItems[currentProduct].inCart > 1 ) {
                cartItems[currentProduct].inCart -= 1;
                cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct], "decrease");
                totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct], "decrease");
                localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
                displayCart();
            }
        });

        increaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(cartItems);
            currentQuantity = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span').textContent;
            console.log(currentQuantity);
            currentProduct = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span').textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').trim();
            console.log(currentProduct);

            cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;
            cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct]);
            totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct]);
            localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
            displayCart();
        });
    }
}

function deleteButtons() {
    let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.product ion-icon');
    let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let productName;
    console.log(cartItems);

    for(let i=0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
        deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            productName = deleteButtons[i].parentElement.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'').trim();
           
            localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers - cartItems[productName].inCart);
            localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost - ( cartItems[productName].price * cartItems[productName].inCart));

            delete cartItems[productName];
            localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

            displayCart();
            onLoadCartNumbers();
        })
    }
}

onLoadCartNumbers();
displayCart();
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it isn't the best form for question, but I will try to answer. Generally, it depends on what you need to do exactly. If you need only html/css/javascript site, which will not save data permamently, you can just send products through http method (POST or GET, that depends on how your code look like). On the other hand, if you want it to be permament you need PHP and some kind of database.

Please, post your code, then I can help you more precisly.

Comment: If you use localstorage you can use it everywhere as long as you have browser open. I belive it will be the easiest way for your needs. You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp. I hope it will help you.

Comment: But how can I see what my client order? How can I see their localstorage?

Comment: Javascript as you use it work only on client site. If you, as site admin or something like that, want to see it on your device where client is somewhere else, you must expand this project much more. And yes, in this scenario it is much better to use some kind of back-end language as php, or use node to make javascript usable on backend.

Comment: I found a tutorial on youtube with making a shopping cart with php and mysql :) but i don’t how i can add products to database... what do i need to click. https://youtu.be/lrIz9C0RNXU this is the yt video. he uses php my admin in 1:40

Comment: You know, this is definitly diffrent question. Please, ask it as new one with your PHP code since you need at least try to do this before asking to meet this site rules. Otherwise your questions will be not enough precise to answer them.